# ICMP "destination unreachable" packet on udp connected socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, udp

I've created connected UDP socket with this function

```
/* Creates connected udp socket */
int
udp_connect( const char *host, const char *serv)
{
    int             sockfd, n;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *ressave;

    bzero(&hints, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if ( ( n = getaddrinfo( host, serv, &hints, &res)) != 0)
        err_quit( "udp_connect error for %s, %s: %s",
                 host, serv, gai_strerror(n));
    ressave = res;
    do {
        sockfd = socket( res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
        if ( sockfd < 0)
            continue;   /* ignore this one */
                /* The call to connect with a UDP socket does not send anything
                 * to the peer. If something is wrong ( the peer is unreachable
                 * or there is no server at the specified port), the caller 
                 * does not discover that until it sends 
                 * a datagram to the peer */
        if ( connect( sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;      /* success */
        Close( sockfd); /* ignore this one */
    } while ( ( res = res->ai_next) != NULL);

    if ( res == NULL)   /* errno set from final connect() */
        err_sys( "udp_connect error for %s, %s", host, serv);

    freeaddrinfo( ressave);
    return( sockfd);
}
```

I would like to do a test how it behaves when peer is actually unreachable. Since call to `connect()` cannot result in this information we need to actually send something. I will describe what do I do and what do I get in the following snippet:

```
printf( "sending to %s\n", Sock_ntop_host( sa, salen));
// prints: sending to 127.0.0.1

Sendto( sockfd, "", 1, 0, sa, salen);   /* send 1-byte datagram */
// prints: nbytes:1
// it is sent, I check via tcpdump or with Wireshark that datagram
// has been sent and ICMP "destination unreachable" comes back from host

printf( "sent, errno:%d,%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
// prints: sent, errno:0,Success

n = Recvfrom( sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE, 0, NULL, NULL);
// never gets here
printf( "received n=%d\n", n);
```

The `Sendto` function is a wrapper over `sendto` that just prints error and exits:

```
void
Sendto(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t nbytes, int flags,
       const struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t salen)
{
    if ( sendto(fd, ptr, nbytes, flags, sa, salen) == -1)
        exit(-1);//err_sys("sendto error");
    printf( "nbytes:%d\n",nbytes); // prints: nbytes:1
}

ssize_t
Recvfrom(int fd, void *ptr, size_t nbytes, int flags,
         struct sockaddr *sa, socklen_t *salenptr)
{
    ssize_t     n;

    if ( (n = recvfrom(fd, ptr, nbytes, flags, sa, salenptr)) < 0)
        err_sys("recvfrom error");
    return(n);
}
```

So the call to `Recvfrom` blocks forever while `Sendto` returnes errno with code `Success`. **How then should I code this to get notification about ICMP response**? is this possible without timeout on socket?

Comment: Whatever is inside `SendTo`() needs to check the return code of `sendmsg()` or whatever system call you are using, and if -1 check `errno` for `EUNREACH.`

Comment: @EJP Sendto is just wrapper over sendto with checking returned code. There is no sendmsg, errno is Success

Comment: There is no such thing as "`errno` is Success". Please post the actual code.

Comment: @EJP Success is a string returned by strerror(errno), errno itself is thus 0

Comment: `errno` is never zero, except possibly when you first start executing your program: maybe not even then. It is invalid to even test it unless an immediately preceding system call has returned -1. That's why I keep asking you to post the actual code. I'm not interested in your description of what you think it does. It doesn't work, ergo your preconceptions about it aren't correct. Post the code.

Comment: The code you have now posted is invalid. You need to test the result of `send()`. If it is -1 you then need to call `perror()` or use `strerror(errno)` in a logging statement. If it isn't -1 there wasn't an error, so the current value of `errno` isn't relevant. Please accordingly amend the code which you continue to refuse to post; post it here; retest; and advise the results. Your present code structure is completely incorrect.

Comment: @EJP I do a test of sendto, and not send(), please don't confuse

Comment: It doesn't change the burden of my comments in the slighest. All Unix system calls behave in the same way, and you aren't coding correctly for it.

Comment: @EJP not whatever, you want a detailed answers from me while confusing more than helping actually. I check for error from sendto call in a wrapper: if( sendto(fd, ptr, nbytes, flags, sa, salen) != (ssize_t)nbytes )

Comment: Nonsense. This is Unix systems programming 101. You must test the result of any system call for -1. It doesn't matter whether it's `send(),` `sendto(),` `sendmsg()`, `listen(),` `bind(),` `recv(),` whatever. I suggest you try it instead of arguing.  I certainly can't help you if you're going to ignore my advice.

Comment: @EJP I do: sendto(fd, ptr, nbytes, flags, sa, salen) != (ssize_t)nbytes and returned value is 1

Comment: You can't possibvly know that with your present code. You would have to store the return value into a variable to know what it was.

Comment: Your `SendTo` error handling is sub-optimal. In case of an error you get no information instead the programs exits. The "succes" prints just what you *want* to send. The non-negative return value would be more interesting, even if it's 0 or any number between 0 and `nbytes`.

Comment: @harper what do you suggest for sendto then? How to handle result?

Comment: What about printing the last error-code instead of exiting the process? Reading the expected number of bytes to send is boring and superfluous.

Comment: So finally you have sent a UDP datagram that is rejected with a ICMP message what you you seen in a network sniffer. An you wonder that your magic function `Recvfrom` does not return. Is that right? Dow you want to reveal this magic function?

Comment: So your previous comment was not needed. You talked about sendto, prompted to suggest code you switched to Recvfrom, OK, it is just:  if ( (n = recvfrom(fd, ptr, nbytes, flags, sa, salenptr)) < 0)
  err_sys("recvfrom error");
 return(n);

Comment: The socket was not connected, thus the ICMP errors were not received to it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you `connect()` a UDP socket, you can use `send()` and `recv()` instead of `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`.  `recv()` will report an ICMP error for a connected socket.

Comment: yes I know, this is not a reason why I had problems, the reason was I was using wrong function, worked on unconnected socket and thought it was connected