# sendto is not giving error on sending

Tags: c, linux, sendto

Hi I have following code:

```
if ((fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
 {
   perror("socket(UDP): ");
   return 0;
 }

 family = AF_INET;
 if((remote_server_ent = gethostbyname2(hptr, family)) == NULL )
 {
   perror("gethostbyname2");
   return 0;
 }

 if (family == AF_INET)
 {  
   sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
   sin->sin_family = AF_INET;
   sin->sin_port = htons(server_port);;
   bcopy( (char *)remote_server_ent->h_addr, (char *)&(sin->sin_addr), remote_server_ent->h_length );
   return (sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
 }

  if (sendto(fd, msg_data_ptr, sizeof(Msg_data_hdr), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) != sizeof(Msg_data_hdr))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in sending data to the server \n");
  }
```

My APP is listing on port 7000 IP 127.0.0.1.
  Now when i stop my application still sendto send the data, it does not give me error. I am always getting the written bytes equal the size of data which i am writting. How will i know if sending is failed or not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`), so you may never find out.  If you need reliability guarantees, use TCP instead.  If you're satisfied with a partial solution of just knowing when the receiving side is completely missing/unavailable, see here: [ICMP "destination unreachable" packet on udp connected socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117719/icmp-destination-unreachable-packet-on-udp-connected-socket)

The general idea is that you can receive ICMP "destination unreachable" errors if you `connect()` your UDP socket and then receive data on it (you will want to use `select()` or `epoll()` for this).  In some scenarios you will find out that your messages are not making it to the other side...but in other scenarios you may not, because hey, it's UDP.